# Gradual underflow and denormalized numbers in IEEE

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I was reading about floating-point representation and underflow/overflow and I ecnountered something interesting - gradual underflow. As I understand gradual underflow means that the result of, for example substraction x-y is so small that it could be flushed to 0 but floating-point system produces number that is smaller then UFL. Everywhere I read that it is made by losing some precission, it means that some bits of mantissa goes to exponent so we can have smaller exponent?

Comment: See this question for an in-depth discussion of denormals and dealing with them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314534/why-does-changing-0-1f-to-0-slow-down-performance-by-10x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively the answer is yes -- the bits of the mantissa go to the exponent. These are called subnormal (AKA denormal) numbers. For example, in IEEE double-precision, the smallest power of two exponent for a normal number -- a number with a full 53 bits of precision -- is 2<sup>-1022</sup>. But powers of two up to 2<sup>-1074</sup> can effectively be represented, as dictated by the location of the first 1 bit in the unnormalized significand. So exponent 2<sup>-1023</sup> has 52 bits of precision, 2<sup>-1024</sup> has 51 bits of precision, ... , 2<sup>-1074</sup> has 1 bit of precision.

(See my article [What Powers of Two Look Like Inside a Computer](http://www.exploringbinary.com/what-powers-of-two-look-like-inside-a-computer/#double-powers-of-two) to visualize this better.)

Comment: Hence, the process of obtaining denormailzed numbers as a result of some floating-point operation is called "gradual underflow".